# Error Login con Angular y SpringBoot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth2

Tengo una API REST con SpringBoot, estoy utilizando Zuul y estoy haciendo el Frontend con Angular, al hacer la petición al login desde Postman me responde con el token cómo debe ser, pero al hacerlo desde Angular me sale un error, al parecer hace el re-direccionamiento a un formulario de login por defecto de oauth.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo un filtro con la configuración del CORS en el ResourceServerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{
...............
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter(){
    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(new CorsFilter(corsConfigurationSource()));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso sucede por las políticas de CORS, no las tienes activas en tu API. por ello con postman funciona. Los navegadores por defecto realizan una llamada OPTION antes que realizar la petición, si la option falla lanza esa excepción.

Puedes agregar al controlador de la API la siguiente etiqueta:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", methods= {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
```

Tambien puedes realizar una configuración para evitar poner esa etiqueta en cada controller, puedes revisar la sección "Global CORS configuration": https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: ya tengo un filtro con la configuración global del CORS en el ResourceServerConfig de Zuul

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que le falten parametros al bean de cors. Te dejo un ejemplo de configuración de un proyecto:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> urlCorsFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> stack = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    stack.setFilter(new CorsFilter());
    stack.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    stack.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST,
            DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR));
    stack.setName("corsFilter");
    stack.setOrder(1);
    return stack;
}
```